# Express.js GET Route method Undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I ran into this problem. whenever I send a GET request on the browser. I received this message `get undefined when using fetch on the browser`.

[image: get undefined when using fetch on the browser]

I do not know why and this is my code.

```
const express = require(‘express’);
const app = express();
const { quotes } = require(’./data’);
const { getRandomElement } = require(’./utils’);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3004;

app.use(express.static(‘public’));

const quotesRouter = express.Router();

app.use(’/api/quotes’, quotesRouter);

quotesRouter.get(’/random’,(req, res, next)=> {
  let randomQuote = (quotes);
  if (randomQuote) res.send(randomQuote);
  else res.status(404).send();
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(Server listening on ${PORT});
})
```

updated

> fetchRandomButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
>   fetch('/api/quotes/random')   .then(response => {
>       if (response.ok) {
>         return response.json();
>       } else {
>         renderError(response);
>       }   })   .then(response => {
>       renderQuotes([response.quote]);   }); });

please helping me out! I appreciate all your help.

Comment: can you add the whole res object of your api ?

Comment: use app.use(’/api/quotes’, quotesRouter) after your route

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tweak to your express code that might be needed. However, fetch is typically a front end javascript thing so are you sure it's being used correctly on the front end?

Check here in the fetch docs to verify you're calling fetch correctly.

```
const express = require(‘express’); 
const app = express(); 
const { quotes } = require(’./data’); 
const { getRandomElement } = require(’./utils’); 
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3004;
app.use(express.static(‘public’)); 
const quotesRouter = express.Router(); 
quotesRouter.get(’/random’, (req,res,next)=> { 
  let randomQuote=getRandomElement(quotes); 
  if (randomQuote) {  
    res.send(randomQuote); 
  } else { 
    res.status(404).send(); 
  } 
}); 
app.use(’/api/quotes’, quotesRouter); <-- moved this to here
app.listen(PORT, ()=>{ console.log(Server listening on ${PORT}) })
```

Comment: thanks for helping me! i am gonna give you my code on front-end above